# how to get the size of Bitmap occupying the an imageView

Tags: android, bitmap, opengl-es, imageview

I am converting each frame retrieved from the camera into a bitmap and i display it on an ImageView. what i want to have is, the exact size of the bitmap displayed on the imageView NOT the size of the imageView itself.
in the code posted below is my attempts and how i tried to get the width and the height of the bitmap. But the code posted below it seems it just gives the dimensions of the imageView itself, because i tested the code twice as follows:

**First Test**:

i set the layout_weight attribute to .3 as follows

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainActivity_imageView_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".3"
    android:layout_below="@id/mainActivity_cameraPreview_container">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity_ivEdges"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and at run time i received the following output:

```
11-14 14:16:16.782 585-681/com.example.textureview_03 D/PreviewSurface: before bitmap.getWidth(): 960
11-14 14:16:16.782 585-681/com.example.textureview_03 D/PreviewSurface: before bitmap.getHeight(): 720
11-14 14:16:16.907 585-585/com.example.textureview_03 D/PreviewSurface: after resizedBitmap.getWidth(): 720
11-14 14:16:16.907 585-585/com.example.textureview_03 D/PreviewSurface: after resizedBitmap.getHeight(): 960
```

**image being displayed**

[image]

**Second Test**:

i set the layout_weight attribute to .6 as follows

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainActivity_imageView_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".6"
    android:layout_below="@id/mainActivity_cameraPreview_container">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity_ivEdges"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and at run time i received the following output:

```
11-14 14:17:33.577 2241-2339/com.example.textureview_03 D/PreviewSurface: before bitmap.getWidth(): 960
11-14 14:17:33.577 2241-2339/com.example.textureview_03 D/PreviewSurface: before bitmap.getHeight(): 720
11-14 14:17:33.667 2241-2241/com.example.textureview_03 D/PreviewSurface: after resizedBitmap.getWidth(): 720
11-14 14:17:33.667 2241-2241/com.example.textureview_03 D/PreviewSurface: after resizedBitmap.getHeight(): 960
```

**image being displayed**

[image]

Hence, i concluded that, the size i am getting in the logcat output is NOT the exact size of the bitmap being displayed on the imageView, however, it might be the size of the ImageView itself

Please, let me know how to get the exact size of the Bitmap that is being displayed on the imageView?
**code**:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        int format = parameters.getPreviewFormat();
        //YUV formats require more conversion
        if (format == ImageFormat.NV21 || format == ImageFormat.YUY2 || format == ImageFormat.NV16) {
            int w = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
            int h = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
            // Get the YuV image
            YuvImage yuv_image = new YuvImage(mData, format, w, h, null);
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
            ByteArrayOutputStream output_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuv_image.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, output_stream);
            byte[] byt = output_stream.toByteArray();

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byt, 0, byt.length);
            Log.d(TAG, "before bitmap.getWidth(): " + bitmap.getWidth());
            Log.d(TAG, "before bitmap.getHeight(): " + bitmap.getHeight());

            //required to rotate the bitmap, because it is initially lopsided
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

            publishProgress(resizedBitmap);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = values[0];
        Log.d(TAG, "after resizedBitmap.getWidth(): " + resizedBitmap.getWidth());
        Log.d(TAG, "after resizedBitmap.getHeight(): " + resizedBitmap.getHeight());

        mIVEdges.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
    }
```

Comment: use `layout_width`  & `layout_weight`  `wrap_content` and try

Comment: @kirankumar i've tried it..i am getting the same size no matter what the layout_weight is!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this line ,

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

makes problem for you. Make rotate matrix by 90deg is ok but width for resizedBitmap is not width anymore . Try this :

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getHeight() , bitmap.getWidth() , matrix, true);
```

I hope this will help you